# give focus back (and restore cursor position) on contenteditable

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, rangy

I have a function that creates a list of autocomplete suggestions when a user types @ + min 3 characters in a content editable div;

When the user clicks on an item in the list, I need to autocomplete and give the focus back to the content editable; unfortunally I'm not able to restore the cursor's position:

```
    $suggestions.on('click', '.list-item', function(event) {
        var newTag = $(event.target).html();
        var saved = rangy.saveSelection();

        $field.html($field.html().replace(/(^|[^a-zA-Z0-9@#-])@([a-zA-Z0-9_]{3,})/ig, '$1<span class="mentionTag chip">' + newTag + '</span>'));
        closeSuggestions(currentWord);

        $field.focus();
        rangy.restoreSelection(saved);
    });
```

The above doesn't work since the cursor is placed at the beginning of the contenteditable;
can someone explain how to achieve this?

Comment: I struggled for a while and went with at.js for a project of mine. Try [http://ichord.github.io/At.js/](http://ichord.github.io/At.js/)

Comment: nice work @joyBlanks

Comment: Well this is not mine. But you can give credit to the developer there at github